# Passing parameter from client side to web method in asp.net telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, telerik

I've 10 telerik dropddownlist in one page. So, I want to bind this dropdownlist using webservice method. But I don't know how to pass the parameter from client side to web method in telerik webservice. Can any one help me please.

Comment: can you please look into below link? I have done for radgrid. http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/08/radgrid-with-wcf-rest-service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnClientItemsRequesting event: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist-onclientitemsrequesting.html

Small example taken from the very article:

```
function clientItemRequesting(sender, eventArgs) {
        var context = eventArgs.get_context();
        context["FilterString"] = "value sent to server";
    }
```